# Why is there more `time_wait` displayed in `sockstat` than it actually is?

Tags: linux, proc, netstat

Why is there more `time_wait` displayed in `/proc/net/sockstat` than it actually is? And how to fix it?

```
[root@node09 ~]# netstat -ant | grep TIME_WAIT | wc -l
28

[root@node09 ~]# netstat -ant|awk '/^tcp/ {++S[$NF]} END {for(a in S) print (a,S[a])}'
LISTEN 119
ESTABLISHED 4245
TIME_WAIT 30

[root@node09 ~]# cat /proc/net/sockstat
sockets: used 5394
TCP: inuse 4358 orphan 0 tw 7599 alloc 4391 mem 1844
UDP: inuse 1 mem 0
UDPLITE: inuse 0
RAW: inuse 0
FRAG: inuse 0 memory 0
```

Expect: The number of `time_wait` shown in `/proc/net/sockstat` should match the actual environment.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your question a `time_wait` (lower case) value and none in `sockstat`. Can you explain why you need to rely on this pseudo-file at all? If it doesn't provide the tcp states at all, why would you use it? Also btw, sockstat: IPv4 sockstat6: IPv6

Comment: Thanks for your response, we use node_exporter to monitor machine metrics, which check socket stats to scrape socket time_wait like [this](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter/blob/6a0598e563213ae95edb6f5152ffc8156abd0932/collector/sockstat_linux.go#L136). `tw` is shorthand for time_wait.